# Using heat capacity to find the final temperature

Tags: thermodynamics

In our thermodynamic lecture, we are studying the heat capacity, for which we took the following definition:

$\delta Q=C\delta T$.

Now if we have the classic case of two objects with different temperature, and we want to find the final one, the following equations took place in the lecture:

$Q_{total} = Q_A + Q_B$

$Q_{total} = C_AT_{A,initial} + C_BT_{B,initial}$

$Q_{total} = (C_A +C_B)T_{final}$

$T_{final}=\frac{C_AT_{A,initial} + C_BT_{B,initial}}{C_A + C_B}$

But this notation/writing makes no sense.

By writing $C_AT_{A,initial}$ we are defining something similar to heat for the initial state of A or B. But we know that heat is not a state variable.

The formula that we are given in the beginning should be:

$\delta Q=CdT$.

And if we integrate:

$Q=C\Delta T$.

The heat absorbed changes the temperature of the system (of an arbitrary quantity) by $\Delta T$.
Shouldn't this be the case? Even though I don't understand how we integrate, because I am considering C as a constant and then integrating over dT, and I don't know whether it is correct. And in the left side where $\delta Q$ is, I don't know w.r.t what I am integrating and, since Q is no state variable, having boundaries for the integral on the right side of $\delta Q=CdT$ wouldn't make sense. I am extremely confused with the notations.

Comment: Your first equation is not a definition of heat capacity. It is defined in terms of internal energy and  enthalpy for constant volume and pressure, respectively.

Comment: That $\delta$ thingy is the most useless piece of notation evah.

Comment: Have you learned about the concept of internal energy U yet, where U is the internal energy of a body?

Answer (score 0):

*But this notation/writing makes no sense.*
I agree as one cannot quantify the amount of heat in a body.

In the equation $\delta Q=C\delta T$ the $\delta$ means two different things.
On the left had side it refers to a small quantity of heat (added or removed from the system) and on the right hand side it refers to a small **change** in temperature, ie $T_{\rm final}- T_{\rm initial}$ is small.

Adding together lots of small amounts of heat can give you a large amount of heat, ie $\Sigma \delta Q = Q$.

Perhaps it better that one writes $Q_{2\to 1} = C_1(T_{\rm final,1} - T_{\rm initial,1})$ and $Q_{1\to 2} = C_2(T_{\rm final,2} - T_{\rm initial,2})$, noting that $Q_{2\to 1}+Q_{1\to 2}=0$ and $T_{\rm final,1} = T_{\rm final,2}$ ?

However in the end it easier to just to write $Q$ and assume that everybody knows what it means?!

Comment: Ok I understand now, because of the way you wrote. I also was able to do it like this, but with your confirmation is better. one additional question: If $\delta Q = C dT$ and we integrate. On the left side we write simply Q since it's not  a state variable then on the left side we should have $C \Delta T$. If I am correct, why did I assume that C is a constant here? Is it because *C= m c_m* where $c_m$ is the specific heat capacity ?

Comment: @imbAF In general the specific heat capacity is a function of temperature. For a sufficiently narrow temperature range it can be assumed to be constant.